# ? in routes.rb with map.with_options ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I'm using named routes in my ruby code.  I come from the phpworld where you'll pass information using `$_GET` and `$_POST`.  I was wondering if there's a way to put this into the routes.rb like this:

```
map.with_options :controller => 'test' do |m|
  m.someurl 'someurl?search=someterm', :action => 'index'
end
```

Currently it's returning `can't convert Hash into String`.  Thanks!

Justin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to just use a Query String, you don't need to tell your route at all. The **params** object will contain any passed parameters.

```
map.with_options :controller => 'test' do |m|
  m.some_url 'someurl', :action => 'index'
end
```

Then when you use the helper method:

some_url_path(:search=> "someterm")

Will create the query string value for you.

However, if you want to pass a parameter to a controller, you can bind them in your route:

```
map.connect ':controller/:action/:id/:search'
```

In your controller you can then access:

```
params[:search]
```

In your case this would up being something like:

```
map.with_options :controller => 'test' do |m|
  m.some_url 'someurl' :action => 'index'
end
```

The [Rails Routing Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html) provides an excellent overview on the subject.